# Binding Datatable data to checkedListBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to bind datatable to checkedlistbox? I was try with this code but the datasource property doesn't initialised

```
CheckedListBox cb = new CheckedListBox();
checkedListBox1.DataBindings = dbFunctions.getTable("pr_fetchLocal'" + editypeId + "'");

((ListBox)cb).DataSource = dtfetchSub;
((ListBox)cb).DisplayMember = "name";
((ListBox)cb).ValueMember = "Id";
cb.Show();
```

Comment: I would remove the part where you set the `DataBindings` to what appear to be a `DataTable`

Comment: also - what platform? WinForms, WPF? ASP.Net, other?

Comment: Why are you casting your CheckedListBox to ListBox ?

Comment: Also does dtfetchSub have some data in it ?

Comment: windows application, Actually i don't know how to bind and refered through net and got this code. so worked with it. Ya my datatable has data.

Comment: foreach (DataRow item in dtfetchSub.Rows)
                        {
                          cb.Items.Add(item["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(item["Id"]));
                       }

But error occurs when execution comes to "foreach" that column name does not find.

if it possible Simply provide me a code to bind the data to checklist box

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the table to the DataSource property like that.

```
cd.DataSource = dbFunctions.getTable("pr_fetchLocal'" + editypeId + "'");
```

It also seems that editTypeId is a string (I am guessing that based on the ' ' ) so this is opend for SQL injection here. You may want to investigate how to pass parameters in ADO.NET :)